# How to find MS SQL Port without admin access?

Tags: sql-server

Im setting up a Ubuntu server in my office which is going to be used for automatic reporting. Ive set it up with the LAMP stack. Ubuntu 16.04 server edition.

Im getting an error when Im trying to connect to one of my companies MsSQL servers through PHP on my new server:

> Failed to get DB handle: SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)

Ive set up my connection with the default port for MsSQL which is 1433. However its not working.

I have READ rights to this SQL Database.

**Are there any ways to find out what PORT the SQL server is listening on? Without contacting the IT Dept. (they are on vacation)**?

Comment: Are you sure it is **MS** SQL server? The error message is referencing the Sybase product.

Comment: @MartinSmith SQL Server and Sybase both use TDS to communicate with clients. SQL Server is build from Sybase by the way, after Microsoft bought it.

Comment: @AlekseyRatnikov - But do they do use the same default ports? A quick google indicates "no".

Comment: @MartinSmith. Absolutely. Reason for messages like this is that PHP is using php-sybase extension to communicate with SQL Server.

Comment: @SAH Do you have administrative access to SQL Server? There are some possibilities for your issue, and they all require administrative access to check it out.

Comment: @AlekseyRatnikov No thats my problem, dont have admin access.

Comment: @SAH Do you have Windows with SQL Server Management Studio installed? If so, you may try to connect to your mssql server with given credentials. However, I'm almost sure that SQL Server's admin simply forget to configure something (there a some steps required to configure remote access properly, I'll describe it in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

[nmap](https://nmap.org/) is a great port scanner.

```
sudo at-get install nmap

nmap -p- 192.168.1.1
```

If your target is not `192.168.1.1` you should change the IP.

Read [this](https://hackertarget.com/nmap-cheatsheet-a-quick-reference-guide/).

Comment: unfortunately that does not work. If I try nmap -p- <the ip> I get the following error: "Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn". So I tried that, and I then get the following error: "Error 485: Your port secifications are illegal....". The host is not down though, I can ping the IP fine from my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is because of misconfiguration of SQL Server. Following steps are required to gain remote access to SQL Server:

1. Enable TCP/IP access for SQL Server: Start -> All programs -> Microsoft SQL Server YourVersion -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server YourVersion Configuration Manager -> SQL Native Client Configuration -> TCP/IP -> right click -> enable.
   [image]
2. Add Inbound rule for Windows Firewall allowing access for 1433 port from required network (or hosts).
3. Enable authentication for both SQL Server and Windows modes. In SSMS, right click on connected instance -> Security -> Server authentication -> SQL Server and Windows authentication.
   [image]
4. Make sure your login (Security -> Logins -> YourLogin) have all required rights.

With all this information, you have to contact your SQL Server DBA and ask him to check out configuration.

Comment: Hi @alek , thanks for your response. However I have no way of contacting the admins during the summer vacations. All I have is a READ only user to the database. And I want to use that READ only user to make some autoreporting through PHP and cron jobs.

Comment: @SAH If SQL Server DBA forget some steps in granting remote access to server there is not so much you can do without his help. However, as I mentioned before, you may install SSMS (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx , it's free) on you Windows host or virtual host (you may also use official Microsoft's virtual machines: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/#downloads) to test connection with your login and password.